# How to calculate and show the value of counter as it changed in grafana chart

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, timeserieschart

I have a counter metric `upgrade_counter` which is incremented every time an upgrade happens. I want to show up a chart in grafana which will tell how many upgrades we have got in last 7 days. I want to show a progression as how the num of upgrades increased over the last 7 days.

I have used following query and it does not correctly show how many upgrades we have received.

`sum(increase(upgrade_counter{}[7d]))`

Value reported in chart is around 40 - 50% lower.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus may return unexpected results from [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). I'd suggest trying [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) instead - it returns the expected results from `increase()` function.

Note that the PromQL query is executed **independently** per each point on the graph in Grafana. So every point on the graph for `increase(upgrade_counter[7d])` query would contain the number of upgrades during the last 7 days ending at that particular point. If you need obtaining a cumulative graph, which starts from zero and increases over time with the number of upgrades on the selected time range, then try the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query:

```
running_sum(increase(upgrade_counter))
```

This query works only in VictoriaMetrics, and it doesn't work in Prometheus, because it uses the following MetricsQL features:

- [running_sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function
- implicit lookbehind window in square brackets inside [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions) for details.